# Windows 7 DNS issue

Tags: windows-7, dns

### The problem

I have this DNS problem once per day, where I can't navigate to any website on any browser but the **already started** downloads or media streaming continue to run fine.

#### cmd ipconfig /all

```
While the issue lasts:

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Home
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : lan

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-E5-49-55-86-0C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.64(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, February 02, 2013 5:37:39 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, February 03, 2013 5:37:39 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Just after the issue disappears:

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Home
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : lan

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-E5-49-55-86-0C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.64(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, February 02, 2013 5:37:39 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, February 03, 2013 10:52:52 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

### What solves it

Restarting the router/windows or just waiting for 5-10 min. But the issue re-appears next day.

### What doesn't solve it

Any of the following: cmd commands I tried like /flushdns or /renew, disabling windows firewall or disabling IPv6.

**Edit**

- Router: Speedtouch 510 (5.4.0.14)
- ISP: LINKdotNET (Egypt)
- Wired DSL connection

Any help with this ?

Comment: It looks like your router/gateway is handling *all* the DNS? Usually your ISP's DNS servers are also used. Can you provide more information about your network setup?

Comment: I'm no expert, but have you considered switching to the Goole DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)?

Comment: @iglvzx Do you mean something like a cmd command ? because I have no idea :)
MarcusChan yes, it is the same problem.

Comment: @RedJohn No. I am asking about how your network is actually setup, e.g. what router model, who your ISP is, etc.

Comment: @iglvzx I've updated the post.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have `Obtain DNS server address automatically` enabled in TCP/IP settings?

Comment: @MarcusChan yes, along with `Obtain an IP address automatically`

Comment: When you reboot the router, does it start working again immediately?

Comment: @TarekFadel it takes sometime until all of the LED are green.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a public DNS server. Use [namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench) to find the fastest resolvers.

Comment: I've used a similar tool, it shows that my local ISP servers is the fastest ones I could use.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though your ISP might be rebooting their DNS servers. I would use a different set of DNS servers (like Google's or OpenDNS's) even though they might be slower, at least they're always up.

What you could do is have your ISP's DNS as the primary and Google's as the secondary. That way when your ISP's DNS servers stop responding you can still DNS results.

Comment: I think the OP said he'd already tried Google DNS and had the same issue, but I may be wrong on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem long time ago in windows XP. everything was working but browsing.

Once you discard the DNS as the source of the problem try to uninstall/reinstall the "client for microsoft networks" in cmd>ncpa.cpl>connection properties.